# Overloading the tilde "~" operator for enums

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, enums, c++14

Is it possible to define operators tilde `~` for enums? For example I have enum State in my example and I would like to be able to write `result &= ~STATE_FAIL;`.
I did something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

    enum State
    {
        STATE_OK                     = 0x0,
        STATE_FAIL                   = 0x1,    
        STATE_LOW                    = 0x2,   
        STATE_HIGH                   = 0x4    
    };

    State & operator|=(State & a, const State b)
    {
        a = static_cast<State>(static_cast<int>(a) | static_cast<int>(b));
        return a;
    }

    State & operator&=(State & a, const State b)
    {
        a = static_cast<State>(static_cast<int>(a) & static_cast<int>(b));
        return a;
    }
     State & operator~(State& a)
    {
        a = static_cast<State>( ~static_cast<int>(a));
        return a;
    }


int main()
{
  State result = STATE_OK;

  result |= STATE_FAIL;    // ok
  result &= STATE_FAIL;    // ok
  result &= ~STATE_FAIL;    // fail

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

> In function `int main()`: Line 35: error: invalid conversion from
>   `int` to `State` compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: The casting of enums is in the other question but it does not show taking the argument by value and returning a value instead of references in the answer by @tuple_cat does for this question. This is important when creating a correct _bitwise NOT_ `operator~`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is caused by taking the parameter as a non-const reference (which cannot bind to temporaries, which the expression `STATE_FAIL` is).

Also there's something wrong in your `operator~` implementation: e.g. your `operator~` modifies the parameter which is not the usual conventional behavior of `~`, as shown [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).

This should work in the expected way, i.e. it doesn't modify its argument and only returns the result of the operation:

```
State operator~(const State a)
{
    return static_cast<State>(~static_cast<int>(a));
}
```

Comment: After playing around this example, it seems that having a non const `State &` as a parameter for `operator~` prevents it from being used. This answer is correct, you must get rid of the reference.

Comment: Having a non-const ref as a parameter doesn't prevent the `operator~` from being used. As explained in the answer, it only prevents temporaries (rvalue expressions) from being passed as the argument, because rvalues cannot be passed as non-const references.